# Body entered function not working in godot

Tags: godot

I am trying to make a node named "gear" change textures when it moves through a certain area, but nothing happens. I tried making it print something when it collides with something, but nothing happens; this problem has been bugging me for days, and I can't find any reason why; its hitbox is working, but the function refuses to acknowledge it

The capitalization is all right. I literally copied and pasted it to no avail. I looked at someone else's code other than the name of that node, and the function is the same; what is going on? [link to the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14j7zy_gFzsk_GDTPjUVqXkyG9E7FVKbD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello. To [make a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it would be good if you could like to the other person's code and show us how that code compares to yours here as we can't see it. Also it would be better if code is not an image, but instead text. Also it seems you haven't shared evidence of connecting the signal in GODOT, and this may be most likely where the problem is.

Comment: @pm101 Actually there is evidence that the signal was connected. In the image you want OP to replace with the code, the green icon on the left of the line number indicates a signal is connected to that method.

Comment: Good observation. In any case I don't think there's enough code shown to fully investigate the problem. Perhaps even if the whole project was available for debug I would at least be able to try it out for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to attach the body entered signal to a RigidBody2D which won't work.

*In order for a rigid body to report collisions, you must enable "Contact Monitoring" and set "Contacts Reported" to a value greater than 0.*

See [[Solved] RigidBody2D body_entered signal does not work](https://godotengine.org/qa/56992/solved-rigidbody2d-body_entered-signal-does-not-work)